# Ember.js view helper binding doesn't behave as expected?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, single-page-application

I have a template with *select* input that controls which view should be currently rendered.
To bind the selected value I'm using the handlebars *view* helper like this:

```
// MyApp.MyViews = [MyApp.FirstView, MyApp.SecondView]
{{view Em.Select content="MyApp.MyViews" selection=selectedView}}
{{view selectedView}}
```

The problem is that the selected view area is not changing when the input selection is changed, the first selection gets rendered and further changes doesn't affect the view.
I've also tested this with the *render* helper but ended up with the same result.
I've made a JSFiddle demonstrating my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/quzqqq2y/2/.
I can force a rerender with an observer + view.rerender(), but that just feels wrong,   is it a Ember bug or am I missing here something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic view type binding isn't supported via templates, you'll either need to dynamically attach the views or refresh the entire view.

Comment: What is the correct way to dynamically attach views? I saw createChildView and appendTo, I'm not sure about what should I use